# Удаление папок в зависимости от времени в отдельном потоке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу сделать такой класс, который будет запускаться в отдельном потоке и удалять поддиректории в отдельной директории в зависимости от времени последнего изменения поддиректории. Безопасно ли делать это в отдельном потоке ?

Как организовать поиск и удаление директории в зависимости от времени ?
Вот так вот получается ошибка:

```
def run(self):
    for current_directory, directories, files in os.walk(self.directory):
        print(current_directory)
        print(os.path.getatime(current_directory) - datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[time.gmtime](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/time.html#time.gmtime)

```
import os
import time

def run(directory=os.getcwd()):
    for current_directory, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        t = os.path.getatime(current_directory)
        tg = time.gmtime(t)
        print(tg)
        print(tg.tm_year, tg.tm_min)

run()
```

удалять в потоке можно без проблем

Comment: Да, удалять можно. Но ведь я еще использую разные библиотеки, например, `os` из нескольких потоков. Это не страшно ?

Comment: Нет, ну только если будете чтото делать из разных потоков с одним и тем же объектом, тогда нужно чтото типа http://www.quizful.net/post/thread-synchronization-in-python